# How can I execute a jboss CLI command so that I can page up, down, or search the response?

Tags: command-line, jboss

Consider the command 'module --help' for instance. The help info for any particular CLI command is often more than a page. On the Linux command line I could write, 'module --help | less' so that I can view the first page of the response and then navigate down and up to read the response. It's hard to believe there is no way to do this within the JBOSS-CLI but I have not found a way to do it yet.

This question is a very specific question about the JBOSS CLI, and not at all a general recommendation for software or some 3rd party tool. I'm asking for a way to accomplish something within the JBOSS-CLI similar to what I would do if on a Linux command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the WildFly CLI command line pages long output by default. Which version of the CLI are you using?
It works like less. Use up/down arrows and space keys to navigate. Type '/' to enter some text to search for. Type 'n' to search forward, type 'N' to search backward. Type 'q' to exit the paged output.

Paging is enabled by default. It can be disabled using the `<output-paging>false</output-paging>` element in the *$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.xml* configuration file or using the *--no-output-paging* command line option.

The feature is present in latest WildFly and in EAP 7.2+

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using JBOSS 7.x, and I don't see that happening.  When I run a command I have to use the shell scrollbar to page back up and see what was missed.  I'm using a red hat VM provided by the red hat training.  I also have a JBOSS 6.4.x install on another VM, and I see the same behavior.  I wish it worked as you described.

Comment: This seems like a relatively new feature.  By new I mean something that was added to wildfly in the last several years.  JBOSS v6.x does not seem to have this option.  In JBOSS v7.x, I have learned that it is a setting that can be changed in the jboss-cli.xml file.  The setting is named output-paging and supposedly it is enabled by default.  However the red hat provided training VMs must have it turned off for some reason.  If you can confirm and update your answer with a bit more detail I'll accept it as the answer. Your answer did help some as it prompted me to search for that setting.

Comment: @shawn1874, I added some details in my original answer. Hope that helps.